# Prolog - Predicate To Detect Connected Nodes In a Directed Graph

Tags: prolog, transitive-closure

I was looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49474648/connected-metro-stations-in-prolog) question, in which we make a predicate in Prolog which finds a path between two nodes ("metro stations") in a directed graph. The original code suggested is the following

```
path(Start, Dest, [[Start,Dest]]) :- connected(Start, Dest).
path(Start, Dest, [[Start, Waypoint]|Path]) :- dif(Dest, Waypoint), 
    connected(Start, Waypoint), path(Waypoint, Dest, Path).
```

However, in order to deal with loops, and eliminate lists which contain them, I tried along the recursion store the stations in which I stopped already, and to check that I don't repeat any of them. This is the code I came up with (note that I don't make a list of lists, rather a list of the stations themselves)

```
alldifferent(_,[]).
alldifferent(X,[L|Ls]) :- dif(X,L), alldifferent(X,Ls).

pathaux(Start, Dest, [Start,Dest],Q) :- connected(Start, Dest), alldifferent(Start,Q).
pathaux(Start, Dest, [Start, Waypoint|Path],Q) :- dif(Dest, Waypoint),
    connected(Start, Waypoint), 
    pathaux(Waypoint, Dest, Path, [Start|Q]), alldifferent(Start,Q).

path(X,Y,Z) :- pathaux(X,Y,Z,[]).
```

However, when I add a rule which creates a loop

```
connected(ataba,naguib).
connected(naguib,sadat).
connected(sadat,opera).
connected(opera,dokki).
connected(opera,ataba). //Note this one
```

I get an infinite recursion! how come? and how can one fix this?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30328433/772868) is the fix.

Comment: @false The solution given in there also does not terminate and recurses forever.

Comment: How did you call it?

Comment: I'm very new to Prolog so I just used the one the OP (you) said path(n,Xs, a,X).

Comment: You need to add your own relation. That is `path(connected, Path, X0, X)` which terminates that is it produces all possible paths and then terminates by failing

Comment: Nevermind, I don't think I have enough knowledge yet to understand and apparently use this generic implementation. Too many components I haven't studied yet..

Comment: ??? Just copy-paste it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Define graph in Prolog: edge and path, finding if there is a path between two vertices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21161624/define-graph-in-prolog-edge-and-path-finding-if-there-is-a-path-between-two-ve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how come?

First, consider the reason for non-termination of your original program:

```
path(Start, Dest, [[Start,Dest]]) :- false, connected(Start, Dest).
path(Start, Dest, [[Start, Waypoint]|Path]) :-
   dif(Dest, Waypoint), 
   connected(Start, Waypoint),
   path(Waypoint, Dest, Path), false.
```

This fragment alone is responsible for non-termination. And if this does not terminate, so does your original program.

Now, to your other program. BTW, your definition of `alldifferent/2` is commonly written as `maplist(dif(X), Xs)`.

```
pathaux(Start, Dest, [Start,Dest],Q) :- false, connected(Start, Dest), alldifferent(Start,Q).
pathaux(Start, Dest, [Start, Waypoint|Path],Q) :-
   dif(Dest, Waypoint),
   connected(Start, Waypoint), 
   pathaux(Waypoint, Dest, Path, [Start|Q]), false,
   alldifferent(Start,Q).

path(X,Y,Z) :- pathaux(X,Y,Z,[]).
```

Do you spot a difference? The list is a bit different, and there is an auxiliary argument, but **within** the fragment, nobody uses this argument. So it is roughly the same. Thus:

This new definition is just as bad (or worse) than your original program!

The most generic solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30328433/772868). See [failure-slice](/questions/tagged/failure-slice) for more on this technique to localize the actual reason for non-termination.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. I don't really understand the code samples. Why are the predicates re-ordered and why are there falses?

Comment: What was re-ordered? I only inserted these **false** goals.

Comment: I misread the code, oops! I fail to see how this code is somewhat equivalent to mine.  It always terminates after the recursive call to pathaux?

Comment: All the goals you added are now behind a **false**. No way these goals can improve termination

Comment: Well, now, but in my implementation they weren't there. What I don't understand is how come the program acts as if there was a false there.

Comment: By adding **false**, the number of inferences (the steps Prolog performs) is reduced (or stays the same). If now this fragment still loops (= has infinitely many inferences) so does your original program. So both programs do not perform exactly the same steps but they are close enough to draw useful conclusions as in this case that they have essentially the same looping behaviour.